# Keycloak restricting realm-management role assignment

Tags: keycloak

I am on Keycloak 21.0.2.
I have a user called "administrator" and I want that only admin have the realm-management roles and no other user can access the realm-management roles and assign them. In other word, calling the below API:

```
POST https://{keycloak-url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm-name}/users/{user-id}/role-mappings/clients/{realm-management-id}
```

with the below payload example

```
[
    {
        "id":{realm-admin-id},
        "name":"realm-admin",
        "description":"${role_realm-admin}",
        "composite":true,
        "clientRole":true,
        "containerId":{realm-management-id}
    }
]
```

should be banned for any {user-id} that is not administrator.

Does Keycloak support it or I should change the source code myself?